# How to get details (like username, password, host IQN) of a particular authorized Virtual Machine and storage target address through REST API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need details of Authorized host(Virtual Machine) like username, password, hostIQN and Storage target Address through REST API.

From Stack Overflow, I got the API by which I can get the mentioned details,

"https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storage_id]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,username,allowedVirtualGuests[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedHardware[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]],allowedIpAddresses[ipAddress,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password]]]]

Method: GET"

Now, as you you know under a particular storage we can authorized more than one virtual machine, so from the above api I am getting response of several vm if several VM are authorized under a storage.

How will I find out the details of one particular VM from the response, do I have to pass some extra parameter with the api?

Comment: please help me out here, do i have to give Virtual machine id as filter.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get that information using [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters), you can try the following request:

```
https://[username]:[aoiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storageId]/getAllowedVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"allowedVirtualGuests":{"id":{"operation": "9222721"}}}&objectMask=mask[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password], assignedVolumes[id, username]]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **[username]**, **[apiKey]**, **[storageId]** and **9222721** (The VM's identifier) with your own information.

---

Just in case, it's not possible to apply filter over **fullyQualifiedDomainName**, but it's possible to use the **hostname**, so, in case that you want to get information through this property, try this:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[storageId]/getAllowedVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"allowedVirtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation": "testhost"}}}&objectMask=mask[fullyQualifiedDomainName,allowedHost[name,credential[username,password], assignedVolumes[id, username]]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: **[username]**, **[apiKey]**, **[storageId]** and **testhost** (The VM's hostname) with your own information.

---

If you want to get this information for baremetal servers, you need to use the following method:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowedHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedHardware)

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowedVirtualGuests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedVirtualGuests)
- [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)